# docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545:

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a problem when i execute the next docker instructions:

```
# make a directory
mkdir /server/nginx
cd /server/nginx

 # make a container
docker run --name nginx \
-d -p 8080:8080 \
-v /home/www:/home/www \
-v /home/www:/usr/share/nginx/html \
-v "$PWD"/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
-v "$PWD"/logs:/var/log/nginx \
-v "$PWD"/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d \
--link php \
-d nginx
```

I get the next error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "/server/nginx/nginx.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" caused: mount through procfd: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.
```

Docker generated the next directories:

drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jan  7 05:03 ./   
                                                                                                                          drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Jan  7 04:49 ../    
                                                                                                                            drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan  7 05:03 conf.d/  
                                                                                                                          drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan  7 05:03 logs/  
                                                                                                                            drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan  7 05:03 nginx.conf/

When need be files not directories.

Answer (score 0):

> drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 7 05:03 nginx.conf/

The `d` above means `nginx.conf` is not a file, but a folder. You could try to `cd nginx.conf` to verify it.

As the error indicates, you should setup a `nginx.conf` file, not a `nginx.conf` folder.

Comment: Yes. Its a folder. But these files have generated by docker...

Comment: You define `-v "$PWD"/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, becaue you want to customize `nginx.conf`, so please delete the folder, and define your own `nginx.conf` before `docker run`. Or, if you don't want to customize `nginx.conf`, delete that `-v`.

Comment: how can i customize nginx.conf if i don't whant the folder nginx? I made 
nginx / – logs
          / – conf.d
          /– nginx.conf
But its the same error:

`docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "/server/nginx/logs" to rootfs at "/var/log/nginx" caused: mount through procfd: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.`

Comment: I want to add the `nginx.conf` for can customize, view logs and the file `conf.d`

Comment: Per you settings, you first need to `rm -fr /server/nginx/nginx.conf`, then `vim /server/nginx/nginx.conf`, add the stuff in this file.

Comment: I get the same error:(

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me starting a container having previously mounted volume from one location, while I assigned it meanwhile other location. After removing and recreating containers from the start, binding/mounting a new volume path, it worked.